# Changing a navbar to show 'contact us' only on scroll

Tags: navigation

My navbar changes on scroll - hiding all links and just showing our contact details.

Docked:

[image: Docked navigation, showing all options]

<sub>On scroll:</sub>

[image: Scrolled, the nav shows contact information]

Is this a good idea? Bad idea?

The objective is to drive phone calls and contact form submissions, but will this create a poor user experience?

Comment: Did you consider putting "on scroll elements" on top of the "docked UI"?

Comment: So the header changes from full content/page width to a mobile header when you scroll down?

Comment: I would hazard that this is a poor user experience, you're pre-judging that the action you want the user to take, is the one they want to take, by removing other options you are limiting the users choice and running the risk of creating a frustrating user experience.

Comment: Why not just have it with the navbar? So you can allow users the freedom to chose wtv they want. Certainly, you won't be getting more inquiries and calls by hiding the rest of the nav items.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I really appreciate it. Some good feedback.

Looks like the overwhelming consensus is: this would negatively impact user experience. A better option is to add the undocked elements to the docked navbar so the option is there, but our users can browse the other pages if they wish.

It also does look a lot like a mobile navbar, which may cause some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend keeping the same content and keep using a fixed navigation where the bar sticks to the top of the screen when scrolling.